# Ratio of amounts of different mono substituted alkanes (by halogenation)

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons, halogenation

[image]

My problem here is the I'm unable to use the information for reactivity of C-H bonds to calculate the amount of mono chlorides. If anyone can help me in the process, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The relative probability of making a primary monochloroalkane related to a tertiary monochloroalkane is exactly $1:1$, out of this decane isomer.

To show how this result is obtained, the number of primary carbon atoms is counted and found to be $5$. The number of tertiary carbon atoms is counted and found to be $3$.  So the number of CH bonds is $5·3 = 15$ for primary carbons, and is $3·1 = 3$ for tertiary carbons.

As far as we can know it, the probability of removing a H atom from a primary C atom related to a tertiary atom is $1:5$.

So the relative probability of removing a H atom from a primary C atom in this molecule is $15$ x $1 = 15$. The relative probability of removing a H atom form a tertiary C atom in this molecule is $3$  x $5 = 15$.

As a consequence, the relative probabilities of forming a primary chloroalkane with respect to a tertiary chloroalkane are the same : $15:15$, or $1:1$.

Comment: Thanks man, I wasn't able to figure out what was going in the question